# What percentage of Stack Overflow have you read?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

What percentage of the questions on Stack Overflow would you estimate you have read?

Has anybody ever mined the access logs and made a histogram of such information?

Comment: I shudder to think how much information there is out there, and how little of it i've read. Then, add to that the rest of the sites in the group and well, i'll be here reading non-stop for the next 6 months!

Comment: According to [this query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/244/how-many-edits-until-strunk-white?UserId=164901), I've *edited* 0.572285% of all questions on SO. lol

Comment: My percentage keeps declining by the second...

Answer (score 8):

If the average professional programmer reads one post every five minutes during 6 hours of the average workday, **they will have read 0% of Stack Overflow**, accurate to about two decimal places

Comment: Well, SO has 700K question, 2M answers and 2M5 comments...that's a total of 5M1 items to read...for 0.01% you need to read 510 items...and Jon Skeet has already written astonishing 0.4% of all answers. O_O' Well, but he does not qualify as 'average'. ;)

Comment: @Bobby: 2M5 = 2.5E6?

Comment: @Charles Stewart: Yes.

Answer (score 5):

Percentage?

Stack Overflow is almost two years old with over 3.14 million posts.

That means that Stack Overflow has received a new post about once every 20 seconds (average) over its life (that rate is *much* faster now).

If you read Stack Overflow 8 hours per day EVERY DAY, without eating, bathroom breaks, or watching Doctor Oz...

and it takes about 30 seconds to find and read the average post...

This hypothetical superman **has read approximately 17% of Stack Overflow.** But they'll know NOTHING about the Most Common Worms in Your Gut, as aired on Dr. Oz. I don't know if that is a good trade-off, personally.

Comment: Heh... I don't know how accurate your math is (because I'm too lazy to double-check it) but I like it. +1

Comment: I imagine it gets much worse once you factor in duplicates and useless questions; I've read very little of SO, but I've managed to read about not parsing HTML with regular expressions about 14 times, and learned all about the CS homework at miscellaneous universities

Comment: I think you are underestimating how powerful Jon Skeet is :)

Comment: And you would have no time to earn 19+ K rep on meta!

Comment: Its actually 3.1415... forgive the circular reference, could not resist :)